# In Mongoose, how do you generate a new field with a value that is the length of another field's array?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I've got a simple database with a collection of users. This is what a document looks like:

```
{
   username: "Joe",
   age: 20,
   friends: ["u2", "u5", "u6", "u7", "u11"]
}
```

I want to create a query that will return something that looks like

```
{
   username: "Joe",
   age: 20,
   total_friends: 5,
   friends: ["u2", "u5", "u6"]
}
```

notice I've sliced only the top 3 friends, since I don't want to return **all** of a users friends in every query.

How can I create the `total_friends` field before slicing it?

Here is what I have so far:

```
UserModel.findById( new Types.ObjectId(userId))
             // what goes here??
            .slice('friends', 3)
            .populate('friends')
            .exec((err, doc) => {...});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation framework. Try this:

```
db.userModel.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            total_friends: { $size: "$friends" },
            friends: { $slice: [ "$friends", 3 ] }
        } 
    }
])
```

Since 5 element array is an input to pipeline stage [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/index.html) will return 5 elements and [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/) will operate on 5 element array taking first three.

Comment: Thanks! But then where does `populate` go?

Comment: @CodyBugstein, modified my answer, use $out to replace existing collection

Comment: Does that change the database?

Comment: It redirects the output of aggregation into specified collection. You can set current one (to replace it) or anything new (like `friends`) to inert those results into new collection

Comment: I dont want to create a new collection though. Sounds like that could get very messy. I just want to return a query result to a user

Comment: Okay so you just need what I originally posted it will return your collection reshaped.